# App stops working whenever I select one radio button

Tags: android, radio-button

I have two radio buttons and if one is selected I want to change the value of `Textview`. I am getting an error. The app stops working when I click one of my radio buttons. It is giving this error on log.

```
 logged error 
>    /com.example.myapp.mttally E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp.mttally, PID: 15125
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4025)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at 

    `com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

..`

My java code on main file is this

```
package com.example.myapp.mttally;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RadioButton lend;
RadioButton borrow;
TextView toFrom;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView toFrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toFrom);

    RadioButton lend = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.lend);
    RadioButton borrow = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.borrow);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?

    Boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.lend:
            if (checked)
                toFrom.setText("   To");
                break;
        case R.id.borrow:
            if (checked)
                toFrom.setText("   From");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Here my **xml** file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="false"
        >

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_button1"
                android:id="@+id/lend"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_button2"
                android:id="@+id/borrow"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/toFrom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does this even compile? You're declaring toFrom as local variable in onCreate(), then reference toFrom in onRadioButtonClicked(), but I can't see toFrom as class variable, or even initialized in onRadioButtonClicked(). Also, read the error, it tells you exactly what the problem is: TextView object on which you call setText() is null, which given the description above, makes sense.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. Please include your xml layout as well as all the Activity Code and the full error log. Otherwise the current amount of information is not enough to determine why you have a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: I have attached my xml file.Yes it compile successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you write something like `TextView toFrom`, `RadioButton lend`, or, more generally `<type of variable> <variable name>`, you're declaring a new variable.  You declare variables called `twoFrom`, `lend`, and `borrow` in two places: once in the `MainActivity` class and once in the `onCreate` method.  So, your code has two different variables that are both called `toFrom`, two variables called `lend`, and two variables called `borrow`.

Consider the `lend` variable. Each copy of the `lend` variable has its own "scope", or the area of code in which it exists.  Since you declared the first `lend` variable in the class itself (not inside any of the methods), its scope is the class.  You can (typically) use it in code anywhere in the class.

Your second `lend` variable, however, is what causes the problem.  You've declared a second `lend` variable inside the `onCreate` method. That second `lend` is the one gets the TextView object...and then it ceases to exist once the `onCreate` method finishes executing.

So, to fix this, your `onCreate` should look like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toFrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toFrom);
    lend = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.lend);
    borrow = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.borrow);
}
```

That way, when you get the reference to the TextView, you're holding it in the variable that will still exist when `onRadioButtonClicked` is called, not in a second identically-named variable that will cease to exist almost immediately.

Comment: Thanx a lot, it helped.